# Aurelia and Materialize: $ is not defined

Tags: materialize, jspm, aurelia

I've been following [this tutorial](https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.gitbooks.io/materialize-bridge-docs/content/installation/jspm.html) to include materialize in my Aurelia project.

I did everything mentioned in the guide:

- run jspm version 0.16.15.
- jspm install aurelia-materialize-bridge materialize
- jspm install materialize-css
- Include override for npm version
- Only import npm version into aurelia app

However I get the following errors:

```
materialize.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at materialize.js:16
    at l.U (system.src.js:4597)
    at o.execute (system.src.js:4597)
    at i (system.src.js:4597)
    at s (system.src.js:4597)
    at system.src.js:4597
    at Object.<anonymous> (materialize-css@0.98.0.js:1)
    at materialize-css@0.98.0.js:2
    at l.U (system.src.js:4597)
    at c.execute (system.src.js:4597)
    at i (system.src.js:4597)
    at n (system.src.js:4597)
    at Object.execute (system.src.js:4597)
    at y (system.src.js:4597)
    at w (system.src.js:4597)
    at p (system.src.js:4597)
(anonymous) @ materialize.js:16
U @ system.src.js:4597
o.execute @ system.src.js:4597
i @ system.src.js:4597
s @ system.src.js:4597
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4597
(anonymous) @ materialize-css@0.98.0.js:1
(anonymous) @ materialize-css@0.98.0.js:2
U @ system.src.js:4597
c.execute @ system.src.js:4597
i @ system.src.js:4597
n @ system.src.js:4597
execute @ system.src.js:4597
y @ system.src.js:4597
w @ system.src.js:4597
p @ system.src.js:4597
h @ system.src.js:4597
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4597
r @ bluebird.min.js:33
i._settlePromiseFromHandler @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromise @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromise0 @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromises @ bluebird.min.js:32
r._drainQueue @ bluebird.min.js:31
r._drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31
drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31
system.src.js:4597 Uncaught Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/materialize-css@0.98.0/dist/js/materialize.js
U @ system.src.js:4597
o.execute @ system.src.js:4597
i @ system.src.js:4597
s @ system.src.js:4597
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4597
(anonymous) @ materialize-css@0.98.0.js:1
(anonymous) @ materialize-css@0.98.0.js:2
U @ system.src.js:4597
c.execute @ system.src.js:4597
i @ system.src.js:4597
n @ system.src.js:4597
execute @ system.src.js:4597
y @ system.src.js:4597
w @ system.src.js:4597
p @ system.src.js:4597
h @ system.src.js:4597
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4597
r @ bluebird.min.js:33
i._settlePromiseFromHandler @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromise @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromise0 @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromises @ bluebird.min.js:32
r._drainQueue @ bluebird.min.js:31
r._drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31
drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31
bluebird.min.js:31 Unhandled rejection Uncaught Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/materialize-css@0.98.0/dist/js/materialize.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/materialize-css@0.98.0.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/materialize-css@0.98.0.js
```

Is this a JQuery error? Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Comment: It appears as though this library is dependent on jQuery. Have you added jQuery to you Aurelia app? You aren't showing any of your config files or your component file that you are trying to use materialize in and that you are getting this error from. All of those would be helpful in diagnosing the problem. Without any of that though, it would seem that you are missing jQuery. Either you didn't install it as a dependency for your app or it isn't being loaded before materialize.

Comment: I've added the JSPM tag to this question. The issue you are having is with JSPM/SystemJS, not with Aurelia.

Comment: You're missing the jQuery dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately, the most current version of materialize-css seems to be missing from the JSPM registry. I think that this may be the reason why jQuery is missing. If you can confirm that adding jQuery (please use v2) solves this, I can update the materialize-bridge documentation.